# Переход к опред. месту c#

Tags: c#

Например есть код:

```
    int a = Console.ReadLine();
if(a == 1)
{
//опред. действие
}
if(a == 2)
{
//опред. действие
}
if(a == 3)
{
//тут сделать возврат в вводу a
}
```

Comment: 1. почитайте про циклы
2. Ваш код не будет даже компилироваться - вам нужно сначала преобразовать введенное значение к int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из возможных вариантов - бесконечный цикл с операторами [`break`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/adbctzc4.aspx) и [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/923ahwt1.aspx):

```
        while (true)
        {
            int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (a == 1)
            {
                //опред. действие
            }
            else if (a == 2)
            {
                //опред. действие
            }
            else if (a == 3)
            {
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

а лучше

```
    bool b = true;
    while(b)
    {
         string s = Console.ReadLine();
         if(Int32.TryParse(s, out i)
         {
              switch(i)
              {
                   case 1:
                        //method
                        b = false;
                        break;
                   case 2:
                        //method
                        b = false;
                        break;
                   default:
                        Console.WriteLine("incorrect value");
                        break;
              }
         }
         else
         {
              Console.WriteLine("can't parse " + s);
         }
    }
```